# Moving objects in OpenGL

Tags: opengl-es

It's my first time to create an iPhone game. I would like to move a ball, I think there are two ways move an object in `OpenGL`:

1. Let each object has a unique `glViewPort`, then change the origin of
   it to move the object.
2. Let each object has a unique `translation matrix`.

I did move one object using `glViewPort`, but not sure if this is the best practice or not.

Comment: By using glViewPort you're moving the camera, relative to the object. To move the object you should use translation matrix.

Comment: I was building over a small project in which simple movement was done using `glViewPort`. As I am extending the project, I think you're right, I need to redesign the project to depend on `translation matrices` for movement.

Comment: As has been noted, a translation matrix is the way to go. Exactly how you do it depends what version of OpenGL ES you are using. You're more likely to get an accurate answer if you include that info.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you are rendering an object (If you are new, I assume you draw within some `glBegin` `glEnd` block) load the GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX and apply your different transformations on it (Translation, Rotation, Scale). The ModelView Matrix should be set before starting your glBegin/End block.

BTW, it is not a wise idea to move the camera too much unless it is really required.